# How to include spaces after a token in batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm using a repl.bat to find and replace files. Here's my code

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%s in (FindNReplace.txt) do (

    Type C:\user\linefeed\%%a  | C:\comp\bat\repl.bat "\%%s" "%%t" X > C:\user\out\%%a 
  )
```

Now in my FindNReplace.txt, I have the sample contents:

```
AAAAA\d{3}      AAAAA
```

Basically all string containing AAAAA+3 bytes will be replaced by AAAAA. Now what if I want to include 3 bytes of spaces for my string to use as a replacement? "AAAAA+3 spaces" Can I include special character in the second column of FindNReplace.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include the spaces in the second column in your .txt file, you need to indicate to the `for` command that these spaces should not be considered a delimiter. Simply indicate that the tokens to retrieve are the first element in the line and that the second token will be all the remaining data in the line.

```
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%s in (FindNReplace.txt) do (
    Type C:\user\linefeed\%%a  | C:\comp\bat\repl.bat "\%%s" "%%t" X > C:\user\out\%%a 
)
```

And, of course, include the three spaces after the value in the second colum.

**edited** to adapt to comments

```
copy "C:\user\linefeed\%%a" "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"
for /f "tokens=1,*" %%s in (FindNReplace.txt) do (
    Type "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"  | C:\comp\bat\repl.bat "\%%s" "%%t" X > "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp"
    move /y "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp" "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"
)
move "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp" "C:\user\out\%%a"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked :) However, what if I want to have multiple lines in my FindNReplace.txt? For example I have 2 line items in my FindNReplace.txt, it always use the last line. What can I adjust to my code to be able to use all the lines?

Comment: @PeterS, This is a different problem. You need to use temporary files, repeating the process for each line, using the output from the previous step as the input for the next.

Comment: I've done this before using this code, Type c:\user\out\%%a  | findstr /viblg:C:\comp\standards\others.txt > c:\user\out\OUTPUT\%%a

Now I cant integrate this code with the repl.bat argument, how will I able to include this code in my code?

Comment: @PeterS, answer updated. As indicated, take input file, parse, generate output, convert output into input, repeat the process. At the end, move the input to the target folder.