# How to find and replace string based on start and end position

Tags: regex, windows, batch-file, text, cmd

I already search the net but I was not able to find any useful articles.

Here's my scenario:

For example I have a file that contains:

```
AAAA            1111
BBBB            2222
CCCC            3333
```

Assuming that the 1111, 2222 and 3333 are on position 20-23. I want to have a file that was being called that is being used to determine the line pattern, start position, end position and the string to be use as a replacement.

Example the file name is replace.txt that contains the following:

```
BBBB    20    23     7777
```

Now, THis file will be called by the batch file that will do this step:

1. Find line that starts with BBBB,
2. Replace the position 20-23 which is 2222 by the 7777 indicated in the replace.txt file.

I already have this code that iterates in every occurrences found in replace.txt file.

```
for /f "tokens=1-4" %%s in (replace.txt) do (
    Type "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"  | C:\user\bat\repl.bat "\%%s" "%%t" X > "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp"
    move /y "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.out.tmp" "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp"
  )
  move "C:\user\linefeed\%%a.in.tmp" "C:\user\out\%%a"
```

Now, how will I implement the above scenario? That finds first the line pattern, the the start and end position, any string found in the indicated start and end position will be replaced by the token 4 of replace.txt.

Expected output must be:

```
AAAA            1111
BBBB            7777
CCCC            3333
```

Comment: Does it have to be a batch file? Batch is terrible for parsing text and there are far better options (PowerShell) available now. What is your expected final output given sample input?

Comment: @alroc

Yes, I just implemented other tool and this is just an additional feature :)

Comment: @alroc

Question updated with the sample expected output :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `repl.bat` and it uses JScript regular expressions, use capture groups

Search expression:`^(BBBB.{15}).{4}(.*)$`

Replace expression:`$17777$2`

The regular expression is saying: from the start of the line, find four `B` characters followed by 15 characters (any character) and capture it as the first group (the parenthesis), then four more characters (non captured) and then all the characters until the end of the line captured as second group.

In replace expression `$1` is all the text matched by the expression in the first pair of parenthesis and `$2` is the text matched by the expression in the second pair of parenthesis.

**edited** to comment contents

file: data.txt

```
AAAA               1111
BBBB               2222
CCCC               3333
```

file: findnreplace.txt

```
^(BBBB.{15}).{4}(.*)$ $17777$2
CCCC XXXX
AAAA aaaa
```

file: test.cmd

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for %%a in (data*.txt) do (
        copy "%%a" "%%a.in.tmp"
        for /f "tokens=1,*" %%s in (FindNReplace.txt) do (
            Type "%%a.in.tmp"  | repl.bat "%%s" "%%t" X > "%%a.out.tmp"
            move /y "%%a.out.tmp" "%%a.in.tmp"
        )
        move "%%a.in.tmp" "%%a"
    )
```

result: data.txt

```
aaaa               1111
BBBB               7777
XXXX               3333
```

Comment: For example I have a file replace.txt that contains 2 columns, Do I only need to indicate token =1, 2 that have values of ^(BBBB.{15}).{4}(.*)$   $17777$2 ?

Comment: @PeterS, yes, as the default delimiters are spaces and none of the two expressions include spaces, it should work.

Comment: I tried this already but it seems that I didnt worked. I tried to have that value as the content of FindNReplace.txt in your suggestion to this page.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860672/how-to-include-spaces-after-a-token-in-batch-script/26861069?noredirect=1#comment42284982_26861069

Comment: @PeterS, I've included in answer my code for testing and the data, replace and output files. For me it works.

Comment: Are you using same as my repl.bat?Can I have a copy of what you are using? Also did you use same code as the code on your answer on this page? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26860672/how-to-include-spaces-after-a-token-in-batch-script/26861069?noredirect=1#comment42284982_26861069

Comment: @PeterS, the repl version in my test folder is 4.1 but I am not using any feature of the new versions. The code I have posted after the `edit` works as shown. Copied and pasted from editor.

Comment: @PeterS, just to be sure, I have created an empty folder, copied into it `repl.bat`, copied and pasted the files shown in my post and the result is the same. Maybe, you have tabs where i have spaces and the character count does not match.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64758/discussion-between-peters-and-mc-nd).

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
 FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q26866198.txt) DO CALL :massage "%%a" "%~1" %2 %3 "%~4"
)>newfile.txt

TYPE newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:: If %1 begins %2 then replace columns %3 to %4 with %5

:massage
ECHO %~1|FINDSTR /b /L /c:"%~2" >NUL
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 ECHO(%~1&GOTO :EOF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "line=%~1"
SET /a endpoint=%3-1
ECHO(!line:~0,%endpoint%!%~5!line:~%4!
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q26866198.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces newfile.txt

execute as *thisbatch* BBBB 20 23 7777

to replace cols 20..23 with "7777" in lines beginning "BBBB"

It's likely to be a little fragile as are most string-manipulation routines in batch - it simply wasn't ever built for the job.

---

This routine reads the file `q26866198.txt`, applying each line to `%%a` in turn and execution the `:massage` procedure. All output from that procedure is accumulated in `newfile.txt`. Naturally, the filenames are nominal.

`:massge` accepts 5 parameters. %1 is the (quoted) input line from the original file. `%2` is the string-to-match. %3 is the start colum to replace and %4 the end column to replace. %5 is the string to insert in place of columns %3..%4 should %2 match the start of %1.

First step is to test whether the line matches the string, so the line itself (%1) is unquoted and piped to `findstr` with output to nul so the test is silent. The parameters are `/b` (at the beginning of the line) `/L` (literal match) and `/c:"string"` (this constant string, which may contain spaces. `%2` is dequoted and used as this string.

If the string does not match, errorlevel is set to 1 and hence the original string is `echo`ed, dequoted and the subroutine exits.

Otherwise, the string matches, so we set up a local environment and establish `delayedexpansion` mode to allow nesting of `!var!` and `%var%` to exploit the `cmd` parsing characteristic.

`line` is set to match the original string read from the file, and the number of columns to be reproduced is calculated (1 fewer than the start column) into `endpoint`

We need then to output the first `endpoint` characters from `line`, then the replacement string (`%5` dequoted) then the remainder of the line after column %4. Since `cmd` starts counting columns from `0`, then we need the substring `!line:~0,%endpoint%!` and the string `%~5` and the string `!line:~%4` concatenated; exploiting `cmd`'s parsing scheme where in delayed-expansion mode `%n`, `%var%` and !var! are evaluated and replaced in that order.

Perhaps the problem with running the code is caused by the fact that the posted sample data has the replace-me data beginning in column 17, not 20 as stated.

Sample data (slightly modified)

```
AAAA               1111
BBBB               2222
BBBB              922220987
CCCC               3333
```

Result data executed as *thisbatch* BBBB 20 23 7777

```
AAAA               1111
BBBB               7777
BBBB              977770987
CCCC               3333
```

Comment: What this code actually perform?I tried to use this but it only creates new file with the same contents as q26866198.txt. Can you discuss what this code actually does?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is match a fixed amount of characters using the following regex:

```
.{30}
```

The above regex will match exactly 30 characters. So what you do in the above example is you match enough characters after the pattern to reach the part that you want to replace, match another number of characters in order to match the part to replace, and finally replace this last match part.

Let's say that the variables P, A, B, and R are the pattern, start position, end position, and replacement respectively. Here's how to do the replacement via regex using JavaScript as a host language:

```
"(?<=" + P + ".{" + (P.length - A) + "})(.{" + (B - A) + "})"
```

Then replace the match. A positive look behind (?<= ) is used to match only the B-A characters after P.

Answer (score 0):

I think the regular expression you are looking for is this:

```
C:\user\bat\repl.bat "^%%s.*" "$0.substr(0,%%t)+'%%v'+$0.substr(%%u+1)" J
```

For example, using yor previous data `BBBB    20    23     7777` the previous line becomes this one:

```
C:\user\bat\repl.bat "^BBBB.*" "$0.substr(0,20)+'7777'+$0.substr(23+1)" J
```

That is: look for a line that start with "BBBB" and replace the whole line by its first 20 characters, followed by "7777", followed by the rest of the line starting at character 24. I don't know if "positions 20-23" are zero- or one-based, but just a minor adjustment is needed in this case.

However, you must use [REPL.BAT version 6.1](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3855&p=37858&hilit=best+of+both+worlds#p37858) in order to use the new J switch.

You may also use my [FindRepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4697) program to achieve this replacement, but you have to insert the modifications described [at this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746983/batch-how-to-store-values-encountered-during-a-regular-expression-search-repl/26748632#26748632).